# Nvidia X Server Settings is not saving the settings

Tags: nvidia, fan, fancontrol, nvidia-settings

I run Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. My problem is that Nvidia X server settings won't save my configuration. I've tried for a long time to make it save, and I couldn't figure out why it won't. I've found many people with this same problem, but I couldn't find a solution. I am no Linux expert so I hope someone can help.

I've seen that under **Thermal settings** the GPU fan speed is managed by *Control Type: Variable*. The ideal thing would be if I could modify the settings of the *Variable*, to make the GPU fan run at the load I want at various temperatures.

If that's not possible it's ok; I set the GPU fan manually, but the problem is that every time I logout or restart the PC, that manual setting resets, and I have to reconfigure it every time.

- Nvidia GeForce 1060 3gb by Gigabyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

First you need to run this command to make sure that you can adjust the fan speed manually

```
$ sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

After that do a reboot or logout and log back in.

Now you need a program from GitHub. Cd to a folder where you want to save it and run in the console

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nan0s7/nfancurve
```

then cd into the nfancurve folder

```
$ cd nfancurve
```

You will see the following files:

```
config
LICENCE
nfancurve.service
README.md
temp.sh
USAGE.md
```

You can use the `config` file to tweak your program later,  but for now we will only need temp.sh

To make it an executable file run in the console

```
$ chmod +x ./temp.sh
```

then to run it use:

```
$ ./temp.sh
```

Now you can add your script to the Startup applications and it will run on every system startup, keeping your GPU nice and cool.

I used the guide [How to control Nvidia graphics card Fan Speed Automatically in Linux](https://www.techticity.com/howto/how-to-control-nvidia-graphics-card-fan-speed-in-linux/).